# apt-get install packages matching wildcards

Tags: apt, regex

I am running Debian 8 Jessie, trying to install PHP command line intepreter from a shell script.

Here is what I do:

```
sudo apt-get install php-cli
```

it tells me there is no `php-cli`.  I do find there is `php5-cli`. However, to make my script more robust, e.g. when running on a recent ubuntu server offering `php7`, I do *not* want to specify `php5-cli`.

I googled for an answer but what I get only confused me:

```
xrfang@P-qapub:~$ sudo apt-get install --names-only "php*-cli"
E: Command line option --names-only is not understood
xrfang@P-qapub:~$ sudo apt-cache search --names-only php-cli
php-google-api-php-client - Google APIs client library for PHP
xrfang@P-qapub:~$ apt-cache search --names-only "php\d+-cli$"
xrfang@P-qapub:~$ apt-cache search --names-only "php\d-cli$"
xrfang@P-qapub:~$ apt-cache search --names-only "php\\d-cli$"
xrfang@P-qapub:~$ apt-cache search --names-only "php5-cli$"
php5-cli - command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
```

My questions are:

1. I do not want the Google API for PHP, so I try to use regex, but as shown above it just does not accept `\d`.
2. Is it possible to use --name-only somehow with `apt-get install`, not `apt-cache search`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Is it possible to use --name-only somehow with `apt-get install`, not `apt-cache search`.

By default `apt-cache search` searches informations from the available package names and their long description. `--names-only` restricts this search only to the package names.

Now `apt-get` doesn't care about description. It will try a package name verbatim, and if not found, will consider the parameter as a regex (while not really documented, actually an extended regular expression). This regex will be used only to match package name(s) from the list of known packages. So there's no `--names-only` option available: consider `apt-get` is under permanent effect of this option.

### I do not want the Google API for PHP, so I try to use regex, but as shown above it just does not accept `\d`.

`apt-get` accepts [(extended) regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended), not [Perl Compatible Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions). `\d` means a digit only in a PCRE and has no special meaning in BRE or ERE. A digit in a regular expression can be represended by `[0-9]` (or for fun `[[:digit:]]` as an extended regular expression syntax).

Your search would be:

```
$ apt-cache search --names-only 'php[0-9]+-cli'
php5-cli - command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
```

To install any php cli numbered version, that would be:

```
# apt-get install '^php[0-9]+-cli$'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php4-cli' for regex '^php[0-9]+-cli$'
Note, selecting 'php5-cli' for regex '^php[0-9]+-cli$'
The following extra packages will be installed:
```

[...]

This will install `php5-cli` and its dependencies.

Please note the usage of `^` and `$` to delimit start and end of the package name selected: once the expression is used as a regex, it can be any part of a package's name, so better be careful. Eg trying `apt-get install .` will attempt to install any package having at least one character: all of them, and will of course fail for conflicts.

For the small details: `php4-cli` doesn't exist in Jessie, but is referenced by an other package ([`php-xajax`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/php-xajax)) that's why it's selected as candidate since it matched the regex. Of course it's not installable so won't be listed in the end.

Comment: cool.  although I used regex for over a decade, didn't even noticed how *non* perl compatible regex looks like !  thanks a lot.